# Mac OS X, Mail.app. attachments disappear in Archive

Tags: macos, mail.app

My system is Mac OS X Mountain Lion, and I am using Mail.app for an IMAP service. It's not gmail, it is a standard IMAP.

When I archive email messages, the attachments sometimes disappear. If I rebuild the Archive folder, I can find the attachments again.

This is so annoying that I need to rebuild the entire Archive folder. Is there any way I can avoid this happening? In my current setting, I enabled "Keep copies of messages for offline viewing: All messages and their attachments".

Comment: Where is your Archive folder located - is it on the IMAP server, or is it stored in the local "On my Mac" section?

Comment: @EddieKelley It's on the IMAP server.